# General relativity algebraic manipulation help

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, functional-derivatives

I'm having difficulty understanding a lot of the fundamentals behind the algebra of general relativity. I have a specific question I'm trying to understand but any pointers about how any of it works with index contraction and covariant derivatives and stuff would be amazing.

The question is as follows:

Consider the expression:
$$T^{\mu\nu} = F^{\mu\rho} F_\rho^\nu-\frac{1}{4}g^{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}$$
Where $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$
satisfies
$$\partial^\mu F_{\mu\nu} = \eta^{\mu\rho}\partial_\rho F_{\mu\nu}$$

Show $T^{\mu\nu}$ is a energy-momentum tensor using the identity:
$$\nabla_\mu F_{\nu\rho}+\nabla_\nu F_{\rho\mu}+\nabla_\rho F_{\mu\nu} = 0$$

I gather that this is equivalent to asking for a proof of the identities:
$$ 1) T^{\mu\nu} = T^{\nu\mu} $$
$$ 2) \nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0 $$

The answer writes off the first as obvious (which I don't see) and gives the following proof of the second:

$$ \nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = \nabla_\mu (F^{\mu\rho} F_\rho^\nu-\frac{1}{4}g^{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta})$$
$$ = (\nabla_\mu F^{\mu\rho}) F_\rho^\nu + F^{\mu\rho}(\nabla_\mu F_\rho^\nu)-\frac{1}{2}F_{\alpha\beta}(\nabla^\nu F^{\alpha\beta})$$
$$ = F_{\mu\rho}(\nabla^\mu F^{\nu\rho} - \frac{1}{2}\nabla^\nu F^{\mu\rho})$$
$$ = \frac{F_{\mu\rho}}{2}(\nabla^\mu F^{\nu\rho} - \nabla^\rho F^{\nu\mu} - \nabla^\nu F^{\mu\rho})$$
$$ = \frac{F_{\mu\rho}}{2}(\nabla^\mu F^{\nu\rho} + \nabla^\rho F^{\mu\nu} + \nabla^\nu F^{\rho\mu}) = 0$$

Any light anyone can shed onto any of the methods used to obtain the results here would be amazing. I understand to a certain level but I just really need some guidance on how to generally manipulate expressions such as this one.

Comment: What is your level of understanding? If you are not able to follow this index manipulation, you are way out of your league trying to learn this stuff now (especially if the first one is _not_ obvious to you). You should go back to the very basics of tensors before trying this.

Comment: I have an understanding of what things mean, I just have a lot of results and I'm struggling to build up a toolbox of the ones that are useful in manipulating expressions such as the one above. Could you suggest a list of mechanisms I should look into/ any resources I could look at to try to strengthen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $F_\rho^\nu$ should be $F^\nu$$_\rho$. Since $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$ is antisymmetric, you need to know which index has been lowered. $\partial^\mu F_{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\rho}\partial_\rho F_{\mu\nu}$ should also be $\partial^\mu F_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\rho}\partial_\rho F_{\mu\nu}$ since you are considering curved spacetime.

1. Since $g^{\mu\nu}=g^{\nu\mu}$, the second term of the energy-stress tensor is symmetric as well. For the first term, we simply have:
   \begin{equation}
   F^{\mu\rho}F_{\;\;\rho}^\nu
   =g_{\rho\sigma}F^{\mu\rho}F^{\nu\sigma}
   =F^{\nu\sigma}F_{\;\;\sigma}^\mu.
   \end{equation}
2. What basically happens here, is that the covariant derivation $\nabla$ satisfies the Leibniz rule and applying it to the covariant metric tensor results in zero:
   \begin{equation}
   \nabla_\rho g_{\mu\nu}
   =\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}
   -\Gamma_{\rho\mu}^\sigma g_{\sigma\nu}
   -\Gamma_{\rho\nu}^\sigma g_{\mu\sigma}
   =\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}
   -\Gamma_{\nu\rho\mu}
   -\Gamma_{\mu\rho\nu}=0.
   \end{equation}
   Using this result, applying it to the contravariant metric tensor also results in zero:
   \begin{equation}
   \nabla_\rho g^{\mu\nu}
   =\delta_\lambda^\mu\nabla_\rho g^{\lambda\nu}
   =g^{\kappa\mu}g_{\kappa\lambda}\nabla_\rho g^{\lambda\nu}
   =g^{\kappa\mu}\nabla_\rho\left(g_{\kappa\lambda}g^{\lambda\nu}\right)
   =g^{\kappa\mu}\nabla_\rho\delta_\kappa^\nu=0.
   \end{equation}
   Therefore you can just take metric tensors in and out of the covariant differentiation, which happens in the second term for example. The two terms of the Leibniz rule can be shown to be identical using this, so the $-\frac{1}{4}$ turns into a $-\frac{1}{2}$. The rest is just simple index manipulation using $A^\sigma B_\sigma=A_\sigma B^\sigma$.

Comment: Ok, I've worked through everything and I understand it a lot better, thank you so much. I've just got a couple of leaps of logic I don't quite understand. Would be amazing to get a quick explanation.

Comment: Sure, I'd like to also help you with follow-up questions.

Comment: Thank you so much. Firstly, is with the result $$\nabla_\mu F^{\mu\rho} = 0 $$ which seems to have been used a couple of times. I assume it is similar to the proof for g, I just wasn't sure how the last lines of this proof evaluated to 0 as you outlined it so wasn't confident replicating it. Secondly is the jump between lines 3 and 4 of the given proof. It seems to imply $$\nabla^\mu F^{\nu\rho} = -\nabla^\rho F^{\nu\mu}$$? But I'm not sure what exactly has been done here. Thank you so much!

Comment: $\nabla_\mu F^\mu\nu$ does not follow directly from the definition of $F$. In general for $A$ arbitrary, it could even be wrong. But you're looking at the electromagnetic field here. The Maxwell equations give you $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=\mu j^\nu$ in SRT, so in a vacuum and using the covariance principle, that states you can generalize a law from SRT to ART by replacing the partial derivative $\partial$ with the covariant verivative $\nabla$, gives you $\nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=0$.

Comment: $\nabla^\mu F^{\nu\rho}=-\nabla^\rho F^{\nu\mu}$ does not need to hold, but it's contracted with $F_{\mu\rho}$, so you can use a trick that is often not directly mentioned in literature. You start with $F_{\mu\rho}\nabla^\mu F^{\nu\rho}$ and split it into two parts (1/2 and 1/2). For the latter, you rename $\mu$ into $\rho$ and $\rho$ into $\mu$, so you get $F_{\rho\mu}\nabla^\rho F^{\nu\mu}$. Now you can use antisymmetry of the first tensor used to contract and you are done. The result is: $$\frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\rho}\left(\nabla^\mu F^{\nu\rho}
-\nabla^\rho F^{\nu\mu}\right).$$

Comment: Amazing, I think I get it all now. Thank you so much for being patient and answering all my dumb questions. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: You're welcome! General Relativity is not easy.